# Azure function that triggers 24 hours after an event

Tags: azure, triggers, cron, azure-functions

We're building an app with Azure that distributes jobs to users. There is a business protocol that if a user does not accept or reject a job 24 hours after creation they get a strike.

So instead of creating a cron job that queries the DB every 10 minutes to find these inactive users, I'm thinking there must be a way to create a timer for every job, which triggers 24 hours after creating the job, perhaps with an Azure Function ?

What's the best way to achieve something like this?

Comment: Look at the Azure Durable Functions monitor pattern: https://hub.docker.com/r/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/

Comment: you could use servicebus and set the `ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc` to delay message processing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.scheduledenqueuetimeutc?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: Thank you both. I ended up using Logic apps with 24 hour delay.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @*Shant Hagopian*, *For providing the resolution here for the problem with building an app with Azure that distributes jobs to users. There is a business protocol that if a user does not accept or reject a job 24 hours after creation*.  Posting the same with my few finding so that if other community have similar issue they can find and fix their problem for the same.

> ***To achieve the above workaround we can create logic app where we can***
> ***delayed upto 24 hrs for the operation***

Also there are other ways as suggested by @Thomas,we can do.

For more information and configuration please refer the below links:-

- **MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**|[***Schedules for recurring triggers in Azure Logic Apps workflows***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/concepts-schedule-automated-recurring-tasks-workflows)
- **Blog**| [***Using Azure Functions in Azure Logic Apps***](https://www.ais.com/using-azure-functions-in-azure-logic-apps/) by @*Matt Schmitt* .